# On-Hold is wasting possible efforts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, on-hold

I think it is way too easy to put a question on hold, and also infuriating at times. In my most recent encounter, I was looking at a maybe little vague question. However in that case, I thought I had a really neat answer that could contribute to the community as a whole. I started composing my answer.

I was all happy until the moment I was trying to hit the 'Post' button. It didn't work, it got greyed-out, all I was presented was the Discard button.

In my opinion it should be possible to still post answers, even after putting a question on-hold, with the following limitations:

- A user trying to post an answer on a question that is On-Hold, should have received at least a reputation of 200 (I am about 400).
- Once a user is already in the 'Answer' screen typing his answer, the user should be allowed to complete and post (well, not really a limitation, but an additional allowance).
- An answer cannot be 'accepted' while the question is still on hold.

That will avoid much frustration, and keep the integrity of this board.

Comment: Looks like you misunderstand what "on hold" means.  Hard to see why, not a native English speaker?  But not being able to post an answer to a poorly defined question is very much intentional.  Such questions have *way* too many possible answers.  Q+A only really works when there's one question with one answer.

Comment: There is already a timespan where you can post a question, after a answer is put on hold. However, maybe you should ask yourself whether or not it was a good idea to answer that question in the first place. Questions are usually put on hold for good reasons. Reasons that usually mean it can't be properly answered. If the OP fixes the question, it can also be re-opened, allowing you to post your answer after all.

Comment: @Cerbrus ^ This grace period is sometimes over 10 minutes! Far too long that a vampire is able to post a very LQ answer. (BTW: You mixed question and answer in your comment :)

Comment: @HansPassant - you really want me fired up completely don't you? Actually you are right, I am not, while I do speak English for a longer time than many on this board. However, my questionable fluency in and comprehension of the English language is not the problem here. When I started answering, it was not yet on hold. So I am sitting here with that answer I really would like to post ... and also I do not feel like cleaning up the whole OP's question.

Comment: Yes, that sucks, 10 minutes of your life wasted.  Nobody is ever happy about that.  The faster SO users vote to close, the less time of your life you'll waste.  We can't really help with that.  It is not a problem that lasts, after you've been doing this for a while you'll get a pretty good feel for the kind of Qs that get closed and you'll know what to avoid.  Avoid the "fastest gun" game, it is never a good way to spend your time at SO.

Comment: @Rizier123: Fixed that mix-up.

Comment: You do have the option of asking a good question (if you can) and self-answering with your answer.  Just because the asker couldn't ask a good question doesn't necessarily mean you can't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question is put on hold for a reason:  to prevent *misinformed* answerers from contributing.  This also has the better effect is users not posting **incorrect** answers to a specific question.

I'm not going to deny that it's happened to me; a question is crystal clear but gets closed for what I feel is an incorrect reason.  I usually cast a reopen vote and save my answer off for later if I feel like it's really worth it.

In these scenarios, the only real recourse one has is to cast a reopen vote (or flag for reopening) and, if they feel the question is worth saving, save the answer off for later and check in on the answer again at a later time.

Or, they could post here on Meta with a link to the post, and ask why this question was closed.  At worst, [the Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/175248) will kick in and send the question's vote score into oblivion, and someone will explain why it was a bad question.  At best, [the Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/175248) will kick in and send the question's score vote into the stratosphere, and you'll get reopen votes.

Allowing users to answer questions put on hold **defeats the purpose**.  But, if you really feel that it's clear, on-topic and answerable, post it here to get others to weigh in (knowing fully that you're seriously invoking the full force [of the Meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/175248)).

Comment: Yeah put the OP's question really is not that well formed. To vague, to broad, to difficult to get it all fixed. Really, the best way is to take that one element that I wanted to answer on out, and post as a new question. Maybe I can pose the question as a new one and answer myself.

Comment: Well wait a second - if you knew the question was too broad, why are you attempting to answer it at all?

Comment: @Makoto: Which is _exactly_ my reasoning for the second line of my answer! Comment +1.

Comment: Yeah but guys, there is a reason why I am only a 400 right ... I am crushed with a combined 56k. I feel like the ant in the sumo ring. I got it.

Comment: an ant in a sumo ring? a bit dramatic?

Comment: I need to accept an answer - now I wonder who has been the nicest so far :-D (don't go and flag it now for an attempt at accepting a bribe I was joking).

Comment: @santiago bet the ant still survives, albeit a little dazed.

Comment: sheesh if you're an ant, at a mere 153, what does that make me? ;p

Comment: @santiago: "An ant has smaller ants, that on him prey; and these have smaller ants to bite'em. And so proceeds *ad infinitum*." (freely after Swift (the author, not the language))

Answer (score 5):

There is already a timespan (grace period) where you can post an answer, after a question is put on hold.

However, maybe you should ask yourself whether or not it was a good idea to answer that question in the first place. Questions are usually put on hold for good reasons. Reasons that usually mean it can't be properly answered.

If the OP fixes the question, it can also be re-opened, allowing you to post your answer after all.