# Please inform user as soon as possible if the question they are answering got deleted?

Tags: feature-request, answers, deleted-questions

It would save me all the time it takes to finish my lengthy answer with links, images and resources.

The question was certainly not deleted right before I hit the "Post Your Answer" button.

So please tell the user the question has been deleted as soon as possible if they are creating an answer.

Edit:
As some comments suggest that this functionality may already exist, please make it more obvious, like making the input text field un-editable.

Comment: This actually would make sense given that SO does tend to close questions a lot.

Comment: How about you simply stop trying to answer low quality questions that will quickly be deleted?

Comment: While @l4mpi's suggestion seems like a good idea on Stack Overflow which has been around for a long time and has a better pattern of what will and won't be closed, it's not helpful to new SO users who aren't familiar with what will or won't be closed.  And it's definitely not helpful for beta sites on the Stack Exchange network.  Moreover, users can self-delete their question regardless of its quality, and the suggestion here would be really good in that scenario.

Comment: @l4mpi How about considering that low quality is not the only reason for deletion? Maybe the user asking the question found the answer and doesn't need an answer any more. I rather try to [_be nice_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and answer a question if I think it's an ok one. After all, If I had considered the question to be uneditable, I would have flagged it as such.

Comment: This should be fairly easy to implement, given that there is a already a similar notice when another answer has been posted.

Comment: See also e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291463/3001761

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett given the 6-8 weeks it took to create Stack Overflow this would be a no-brainer....

Comment: @l4mpi: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824426/how-to-use-topological-sort-on-a-graph-with-circles) - it was certainly not low-quality, and I got a good answer to it, but the OP rage-deleted his question before I could post.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but i'm pretty sure I have seen a "This Question has been deleted" popup before.. Might have been something else though.

Comment: I just received a "This question has been deleted -- no more answers will be accepted." drop-down notification for a question I was answering on Meta.SO. (I regret I didn't take a screenshot.) Deletion-notification functionality *does already exist*, but maybe it's not perfectly reliable.

Comment: @apsillers I added that information to the question.

Comment: Per MetaSE, *"If a question is closed while you're answering on the full version of the site, you will receive a notification that the question was closed and the 'Post Your Answer' button will be disabled. However, this is only a client-side restriction, so it is possible in some cases that this process fails. When it does, the backend allows for a grace period of around four hours"* - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/248731

Comment: The notification should also take into account [the Stack Snippet Editor when it is visible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379350/215552)...