# Suggestion: Snippet Editor Notification when the question has been deleted

Tags: feature-request

I was writing code snippet to answer a question.
I had been doing it for a while and when I finished I found that the question was deleted (maybe long) before I finished doing the snippet.

So, I would like to request a notification feature to alert in the snippet editor to let the user know that the question has been deleted therefore no point doing it anymore.

Comment: I have already seen the notification when the question has been deleted on the normal answer textfield but not on the snippet editor. So, that is the difference, isn't it?

Comment: It's been a while since I participated in tags which really use snippets so I'd completely forgotten how annoying this can be. This used to be one of my biggest gripes about SO user experience.